# Find $\lim \limits_{x \to \pi}\frac{\int_0^x\cos^2(t)dt}{x-\pi}\;$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \pi}\frac{\int_0^x\cos^2(t)\,dt}{x-\pi}$$

I don't understand why the limit is not $\infty$

How is the limit: $1$?

Comment: But L'Hopital's rule? $x -> \pi$ and not 0

Comment: $f^{\prime}(c) = \lim\limits_{x \to c}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$

Comment: @Lee L'Hospital's rule works no matter what $x$ approaches in the limit.

Comment: but how do I know then that I have "0"/"0"?

Comment: @Lee Ah, Now I see what you mean. Well, it seems that we all misread your question. Indeed, the limit as it is posted now does not exist. It is *not* equal to $1$, and is also not equal to $\infty$, it just does not exist.

Comment: You are right. It is $\infty$.

Comment: @Clarinetist Well, the first limit is not $0$.

Comment: @Kyson Actually, it is not $0$, only the right limit is $\infty,$ the left is $-\infty$. The whole limit does not exist.

Comment: @Kyson: No, the limit does not exist. It is not $\infty$ because the sign depends on the direction of approach.

Comment: so the answer in the book is incorrect:|
But why did you think that it is 1?
And also, it would have been correct to use L'Hopital' only when the limit approaches to 0 right?

Comment: @Lee No, because as $x$ approaches $0$, the denominator is not $0$, so no L'hospital. I think the answer in the book calculates the limit if the lower bound of the integral is set to $\pi$ instead of $0$.

Comment: Ah ok great got it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that

$$\int \cos ^2 (x)dx = \frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sin(2x)}{4}$$

This is easy to see kowing that $\cos^2(x)= \frac{\cos(2x)+1}{2}$ (verify!). Hence

$$\int^x_0 \cos ^2 (t)dt = \frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sin(2x)}{4}=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{2}$$

(remember that $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$).

Then

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \pi}\frac{\int_0^x\cos^2(t)\,dt}{x-\pi}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{x+\cos(x)\sin(x)}{x-\pi}$$

This last limit doesn't exist (check the limit as $x\to \pi^-$ and as $x\to\pi^+$).

Answer (score 0):

If you put $$f(x)=\int_0^x cos^2(t)dt $$ so it's simple to see that $f(\pi)=K>0$ and so :
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi }\frac{f(x)}{x-\pi }=\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi }\frac{f(x)-f(\pi)}{x-\pi }+\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi }\frac{f(\pi)}{x-\pi }=f'(\pi)+\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi }\frac{f(\pi)}{x-\pi }=\pm\infty
$$

Comment: You can only use the additivity of limits if both pieces being added have a finite limit.